# TSQL SSRS Cross Reference another column

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

```
ID   | Col2 | Col3 | SequenceNum   
--------------------------------   
1    |  x   |  12  |  5
2    |  y   |  11  |  6    
3    |  a   |  45  |  7    
100  |  b   |  23  |  8   
101  |  a   |  16  |  9    
102  |  b   |  28  |  10    
4    |  a   |  9   |  11
5    |  b   |  26  |  12
6    |  x   |  100 |  13
```

I have an SSRS report at the moment which you can enter the `ID` for and it'll show you data for those ID's. For example lets say you enter start `ID` **2** end `ID` **5** it'll report back **2,3,4,5** with `Col2` and `Col3` data.

But what I really want to happen is for it to return **2,3,100,101,102,3,4,5**

I believe may be some way to cross reference the `SequenceNum` column but I'm fairly new to SQL and SSRS can anyone help?

So an user would enter a parameters... 
`start-ID` = **2** which has a `SequenceNum` of **6**
and `end-ID` = **5**  which has an `SequenceNum` of **12**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using SSRS you can specify a `Value` and a `Label` for your parameters.

Create a dataset with the following SQL as the source:

```
select distinct ID as Label
               ,SequenceNum as Value
from YourTable
order by SequenceNum
```

And then in the properties for your parameter, in `Available Values` select `Get values from query` and then select the above dataset.  Set the `Value field` and `Label field` as your label and value columns and then click `OK`.  You will need to do this for your start and end parameters, using the same dataset.

Your parameters will now be drop down menus that display the `ID` value to the user, but passes the `SequenceNum` value to your query.  You can then use these to filter your main dataset.

Answer (score 4):

Extract your starting and ending sequence numbers from value supplied by starting id and ending id respectively and use them in WHERE condition as below

```
DECLARE @StartingSeqNum INT, @EndingSeqNum 
SELECT @StartingSeqNum  = SeqNum FROM tableName  WHERE ID = @start_id
SELECT @EndingSeqNum = SeqNum FROM tableName  WHERE ID = @end_id

SELECT Col2,Col3
FROM tableName
WHERE SeqNum BETWEEN @StartingSeqNum AND @EndingSeqNum
```

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach.  Use the inbuilt SSRS parameter functionality instead.